# Google spread sheet error when using SpreadsheetApp.getUi() function

Tags: google-apps-script

Whenever i try to run the script below in google app.

```
function onOpen()
{
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(SKA).addItem("refresh", "deniminator_heading_rebuild")
}
```

i get the following error message.

```
"SpreadsheetApp.getUi() can only be called from a script bound to the new version of Google Sheets"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your spreadsheet was created using the old version of Google Sheets ;)

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3544847?hl=en